# How can I join these 2 join queries?

Tags: mysql, inner-join

Can anyone help me join these 2 join queries?  I tried putting the ON and WHERE statements of the second query into the first query but that didn't give me the results I was looking.  Below are the 2 queries that give me the result I am looking for but I would like to combine them.

```
SELECT username FROM Login 
INNER JOIN Friends 
ON Login.id = Friends.userid2 
WHERE Friends.userid1 = 41


SELECT username FROM Login
INNER JOIN Friends
ON Login.id = Friends.userid1
WHERE Friends.userid2 = 41
```

Comment: This isn't exactly clear. Give an example of your desired output. You want all the logged in user's friends? What's going on here?

Comment: The userid1 and the userid2 column both have an undefined number of rows with 41.  For example if userid1 = 41 three times, return the three corresponding userid2 rows and grab the username from Login based on userid2.  That's what the 1st query does.  I also want to do the same for userid2.  userid2 = 41 x times, return corresponding userid1 rows...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT username FROM Login 
INNER JOIN Friends 
ON (Login.id = Friends.userid2 AND Friends.userid1 = 41)
    OR (Login.id = Friends.userid1 AND Friends.userid2 = 41)
```

Comment: Neither of these do the trick.  My comment above might clear things up.

Answer (score 0):

Given your description:

```
SELECT username FROM Login 
INNER JOIN Friends 
ON Login.id = Friends.userid2 
WHERE Friends.userid1 = 41
UNION
SELECT username FROM Login
INNER JOIN Friends
ON Login.id = Friends.userid1
WHERE Friends.userid2 = 41
```